# Change Value Displayed in v-slider and v-text-field based on a v-select option

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have run into a quite interesting problem I cannot seem to wrap my head around.

I have a form that consists of multiple `<v-slider>`s and `<v-text-field>`s. for each attribute of an object there is a slider and text field using it as their v-model as follows:

```
<v-slider v-model='object1.value'></v-slider>
<v-text-field v-model='object1.value'></v-text-field>
```

The issue is these fields (as they are retrieved from the Database) come out in seconds which can be a burden on a user when entering values that could be more easily be represented as hours or minutes. I have a `<v-select>` that allows the user to select hours or minutes, however I cannot figure out how to change the value of the sliders and text fields to display the value as hours.

Example:

1. value of the slider is 3600 (in seconds).
2. User selects `hours` from the dropdown
3. `3600` should then be changed to `1`

I have tried setting a watcher on the change in the dropdown, which consistently returns `NaN` when doing my math on the values supplied.

Does anyone have any ideas to solve this?

EDIT:
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/aturingmachine/pen/Gdvwvz)

EDIT 2:
So it seems a `computed` property may be what I am looking for, however I cannot for the life of me get it to work. I may just move these values bound to my inputs to other variables and reassign them on form submission.

Comment: Do you have a codepen or something to work on ?

Comment: @Toodoo Give me a minute and I can slap one together for you to look at with an idea of what I am trying to do

Comment: @Toodoo here:
https://codepen.io/aturingmachine/pen/Gdvwvz
Let me know if you need anything else! Thank you ahead of time

Comment: Edit your question to add it ;)

Comment: I managed to do some thing but not all you want i think : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJELeG It print the right value based on select value but slider is still in minute (binded on obj)

Comment: @Toodoo yeah that seems to be the problem, this is closer though so thank you. I may be able to just remove the slider if they are using minutes or hours as that makes more sense maybe. Let me know if you can figure it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) that scales the original value according to the selected time unit.
Based on your original pen, here is what you'd need to change:

In the select, add the number of seconds for the time unit as value - this is your conversion factor

```
<v-select 
  :items=[
    {text: 'Seconds', value: 1},
    {text: 'Minutes', value: 60},
    {text: 'Hours', value: 3600}
  ]" 
  v-model="conversionFactor"
/>
```

the computed property divides by the conversion factor on get and multiplies by the factor on write:

```
computed: {
  convertedValue: {
    get: function() {
      return this.exObj.value / this.conversionFactor
    },
    set: function(newValue) {
      this.exObj.value = newValue * this.conversionFactor
    }
  }
}
```

In addition, you might want to scale the slider maximum value based on the selected conversion as well:

```
<v-slider 
  v-model="convertedValue" thumb-label
  :max='9999 / conversionFactor'
  :min='0' 
/>
```

Here's a [working pen](https://codepen.io/wwerner/pen/MXbyjL): https://codepen.io/wwerner/pen/MXbyjL

Comment: I wound up going a different route, which may or may not be less efficient. One issue I had was there are multiple inputs on the page, and they do not all use the same sub units and may not even have sub units. However this answer answers my question as posted! Thank you!